# How can I turn Google fonts into a png or gif?

Tags: fonts, typography, google-font-api

I've been using a Google font as my web app's logo. But it seems that it doesn't render as great as I expected. But I still love the font face I've been using. So I want to just turn that into a png or gif and use the image as the logo.

What is the easiest way to do something like this?

Comment: Are you sure you've set it up properly? Since the idea of web fonts is to /not/ have to use a picture instead.

Comment: I'm overlaying the font on top of flash with wmode=opaque(or transparent), and that seems to break things on Webkit based browsers. The font appear dirty.

Comment: Let us know if one of our answers was helpful or on-target. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Aatch is right about the idea of Web fonts is not having to create images, you can always download the font to your computer and create the logo in Photoshop.

Answer (score 5):

I found this fantastic site to help you convert the Google Fonts Text into an Image. The site is [Picas](https://picas.vercel.app/). [Picas](https://picas.vercel.app/) is Open Source. You can find out the Source Code in their repo.

See https://picas.vercel.app/.

See Source Code https://github.com/djyde/Picas.

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: This works perfect! The text with a transparent background!

Answer (score 1):

Take a screenshot of the text rendered in the browser that renders it best. Ctrl-PrintSrc in KDE and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

take a screenshot
on Mac: CMD+Shift+4
on Windows: open the print screen program
on Linux: PrintSrc

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot, crop it in Photoshop.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same need to have static images of google fonts.

It was a huge timesink so I ended up automating it with puppeteer/lambda. I have up to date renders of every google font available for download @ [gfontpng.com](https://gfontpng.com/)